# Can I declare a new variable inside a SASS mixin?

Tags: css, variables, sass, mixins

I have the following SASS mixin:

```scss
@mixin gradient($start, $end, $fallback: $end, $direction: bottom) {
    @if $direction == top {
        $directionOld: bottom;
    } @else if $direction == right {
        $directionOld: left;
    } @elseif $direction == bottom {
        $directionOld: top;
    } @elseif $direction == left {
        $directionOld: right;
    }

    background: $fallback;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($directionOld, $start, $end);
    background:         linear-gradient(to $direction, $start, $end);
}
```

This mixin throws an error because $directionOld is not defined.
I can fix it adding this variable by default to the mixin params:

```scss
@mixin gradient($start, $end, $fallback: $end, $direction: bottom, $directionOld: top) {
    @if $direction == top {
        $directionOld: bottom;
    } @else if $direction == right {
        $directionOld: left;
    } @elseif $direction == bottom {
        $directionOld: top;
    } @elseif $direction == left {
        $directionOld: right;
    }

    background: $fallback;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($directionOld, $start, $end);
    background:         linear-gradient(to $direction, $start, $end);
}
```

But this is not as clean as I want, is there any error in the first code?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What is your goal with this code block?

Comment: Have you looked at existing libraries rather than rolling your own mixins?  http://compass-style.org/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can define new variable in Mixin but you have to define it before use it in an if statement.

I write your code again:

```scss
@mixin gradient($start, $end, $fallback: $end, $direction: bottom) {
    $directionOld:top !default;
    
    @if $direction == top {
        $directionOld: bottom;
    } @else if $direction == right {
        $directionOld: left;
    } @elseif $direction == bottom {
        $directionOld: top;
    } @elseif $direction == left {
        $directionOld: right;
    }
    
    background: $fallback;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($directionOld, $start, $end);
    background:         linear-gradient(to $direction, $start, $end);
}
```